# PHP writing a gzip to file

Tags: php, csv, gzip

I am downloading a gzip csv and writing the un-zipped string to a file. Using:

```
$file = gzopen($this->getTmpZipFileName(), 'rb');
$outPutFile = fopen($uncompressedFileName, 'wb');

while(!gzeof($file)){
        fwrite($outPutFile, gzgets($file, $bufferSie));
    }
```

At some point during this process something is breaking with a space " ". It is treating the " " as a new line. Which of course will 'break' the csv.

I believe it is something to do with the uncompressing of the gzip file. If I dump out

```
var_dump(var_dump(gzread($file,100000)));
die();
```

I get the same issue.

Uncompressing the csv through terminal the csv file is fine.

I am at a loss of what else I can try to open the file correctly.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Interestingly if I gzip a txt file split on | then the uncompressed file has no line breaks. Whilst uncompressing again on a terminal does include the line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out when I was creating the gzip file something was messed up with the compression. Using another file from another source works as expected. This has driven me mad!!